# How to approach the generation of tables based on conditionals using xtable

Tags: r, format, xtable, stargazer, kableextra

I am only in the beginning of the use of packages like `xtable` or `stargazer. Bellow is a sample dataset, the original one is much larger.

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(rep(
    sample(c(2012,2016),10, replace = T)),
    sample(c('Treat','Control'),10,replace = T),
    runif(10,0,1),
    runif(10,0,1),
    runif(10,0,1))

colnames(df) <- c('Year','Group','V1','V2','V3')
```

I would like to generate well-formatted tables displaying descriptive statistics for the data set above.

However, is there a way `xtable` could directly generate a table in which I can see statistics for the whole dataset, separating by group (Treat and Control) and by year (2012, 2016)? Or maybe even by combining groups and years?

Or should I filter the original df according to these settings and run `xtable` on each one?

Another thing I would want is to, instead of displaying the **mean**, display the **median** of the variables, among other statistics. Is it possible, or do I have to manually calculate that using R?

Any solutions considering `stargazer` are valid!

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Below are some examples of what you can do in an `rmarkdown` document, although you can go a lot further in formatting the table than I've done here. I've included some examples using `xtable` and then a couple of examples with the new `kableExtra` package, which, unless you're already skilled with `latex`, makes it easier to format complex table layouts when compared with `xtable`. See the vignettes for [**`xtable`**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xtable/vignettes/xtableGallery.pdf) and [**`kableExtra`**](http://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf) for more information.

For summarizing and reshaping the data, I've used functions from the `dplyr` and `tidyr` packages (which are part of the `tidyverse` suite of packages). You can also summarize and reshape with base R functions, such as `aggregate` and `reshape`, and with the `data.table` package.

### `rmarkdown` document

````
---
title: "Tables"
author: "eipi10"
date: "7/7/2017"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE)
library(xtable)
options(xtable.comment=FALSE, xtable.include.rownames=FALSE)
library(tidyverse)
```

```{r}
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(Year=rep(
    sample(c(2012,2016), 10, replace = T)),
    Group=sample(c('Treat','Control'),10,replace = T),
    V1=runif(10,0,1),
    V2=runif(10,0,1),
    V3=runif(10,0,1))
```

```{r, results="asis"}
# Mean by Year and Group
summary.table = df %>% 
               group_by(Year, Group) %>%
               summarise_all(funs(mean))

print(xtable(summary.table, 
             caption="Mean by Year and Group",
             digits=c(1,0,0,2,2,2)))
```

```{r, results="asis"}
# Median by Year and Group
summary.table = df %>% 
               group_by(Year, Group) %>%
               summarise_all(funs(median))

print(xtable(summary.table, 
             caption="Median by Year and Group",
             digits=c(1,0,0,2,2,2)))
```

```{r, results="asis"}
# Mean and Median by Year and Group
summary.table = df %>% 
               group_by(Year, Group) %>%
               summarise_all(funs(mean, median))

print(xtable(summary.table, 
             caption="Mean and Median by Year and Group",
             digits=c(1,0,0,rep(2,6))))
```

```{r}
# Create a function that takes the summary function calls as arguments
xtab_fnc = function(data, caption, ...) {

  # quosure to dispatch functions properly (see Programming with dplyr vignette)
  funcs = quos(...)

  summary.table = data %>% 
    group_by(Year, Group) %>%
    summarise_all(funs(!!!funcs))

  # Get rid of repeated years
  for(i in nrow(summary.table):2) {
    if(identical(summary.table$Year[i-1], summary.table$Year[i])) {
      summary.table$Year[i] = ""
    }
  }

  xtable(summary.table, 
         caption=caption,
         digits=c(1,0,0,rep(2,ncol(summary.table) - 2)))
}
```

```{r, results="asis"}
# Run the function
print(xtab_fnc(df, "Mean, Median, and Sum by Year and Group", mean, median, sum),
      size="scriptsize")
```

```{r, results="asis"}
# Run the function
print(xtab_fnc(df, "Mean by Year and Group", mean),
      size="large")
```

```{r}
# You can do more complex formatting in xtable, but it's probably easier with kableExtra
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
```

```{r}
summary.table = df %>% 
  group_by(Year, Group) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(mean,sd,min,median,max))

# Get rid of repeated years
for(i in nrow(summary.table):2) {
  if(identical(summary.table$Year[i-1], summary.table$Year[i])) {
    summary.table$Year[i] = ""
  }
}

# Get rid of "_mean", and "_median" in column names
names(summary.table) = gsub("_.*","",names(summary.table))

# LaTeX Table
kable(summary.table, format = "latex", 
      booktabs = T, caption = "kableExtra to format spanning columns",
      digits=c(0,0,rep(3,15))) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped", "hold_position", "scale_down"),
                full_width=F) %>%
  add_header_above(c("","","Mean"=3,"SD"=3,"Min"=3,"Median[note]"=3,"Max"=3)) %>%
  add_footnote(c("Note, means and medians are often the same with this data."))
```

```{r}
# Reshape table to turn V1-V3 into rows
summary.table = df %>% 
  group_by(Year, Group) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(mean,sd,min,median,max)) %>% 
  gather(key, value, -Year, -Group) %>%
  separate(key, into=c("var", "stat")) %>%
  unite(stat_Group, stat, Group) %>%
  spread(stat_Group, value) 

# Get rid of repeated years
for(i in nrow(summary.table):2) {
  if(identical(summary.table$Year[i-1], summary.table$Year[i])) {
    summary.table$Year[i] = ""
  }
}

names(summary.table) = gsub(".*_", "", names(summary.table))

# LaTeX Table
kable(summary.table, format = "latex", 
      booktabs = T, caption = "kableExtra to format spanning columns",
      digits=c(0,0,rep(3,10))) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped", "hold_position", "scale_down"),
                full_width=F) %>%
  add_header_above(c("","","Max"=2,"Mean"=2,"Median"=2,"Min"=2,"SD"=2)) 
```

```{r}
# Reshape table to turn V1-V3 into rows; also add a column summarizing all subjects
summary.table = df %>% 
  group_by(Year, Group) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(mean,sd,min,median,max)) %>% 
  bind_rows(df %>%                                              # bind_rows block adds the "All" column
              mutate(Group="All") %>%                           # | 
              group_by(Year, Group) %>%                         # |
              summarise_all(funs(mean,sd,min,median,max))) %>%  # |
  gather(key, value, -Year, -Group) %>%
  separate(key, into=c("var", "stat")) %>%
  unite(stat_Group, stat, Group) %>%
  spread(stat_Group, value) 

# Get rid of repeated years
for(i in nrow(summary.table):2) {
  if(identical(summary.table$Year[i-1], summary.table$Year[i])) {
    summary.table$Year[i] = ""
  }
}

names(summary.table) = gsub(".*_", "", names(summary.table))

# LaTeX Table
kable(summary.table, format = "latex", 
      booktabs = T, caption = "kableExtra to format spanning columns; also add an 'All' column",
      digits=c(0,0,rep(3,15))) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped", "hold_position", "scale_down"),
                full_width=F) %>%
  add_header_above(c("","","Max"=3,"Mean"=3,"Median"=3,"Min"=3,"SD"=3)) 
```
````

### PDF Output File

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you! But is there a way that I can make the package give me the other statistics that it usually gives. Eg: standard deviation, min., max. And the median, instead of the mean?

Comment: Yes, just pass those functions to `funs()` in `summarise_all`. I've added those summary functions to the very last example (the one that uses the `kableExtra` package to render the table into Latex).

Comment: Actually, the last two examples in the updated answer.

Comment: Can I transpose these results? The table would be too large since there a lot of variables. It would fit better if xtable gave me the group/year on the columns and mean/median etc on the rows

Comment: Shape the table into the form you want before feeding it to `xtable`. My answer has a couple of examples of data reshaping, but take a look at the `dplyr` and `tidyr` vignettes for more information on doing this with `tidyverse` functions. You can also summarise and reshape data using the `data.table` package, or with base R functions such as `aggregate` and `reshape`.

Comment: is there a way I could display results for Controls, Treaties and the whole sample?? Thank you

Comment: I've added another code chunk at the end of the `rmarkdown` document to show one way to add a column for the whole sample. This is really a data summarizing and reshaping task that isn't specific to output functions such as `xtable`.